# Laravel overrides named route and takes wrong one

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have this defined in my routes.php file

```
Route::post('gestionAdministrador', array('as' => 'Loguearse', 'uses' => 'AdministradorController@Login'));

Route::post('gestionAdministrador', array('as' => 'RegistrarAdministrador', 'uses' => 'AdministradorController@RegistrarAdministrador'));
```

And in my login.blade.php file, the form starts as this

```
{{ Form::open(array('route'=>'Loguearse'))}}
```

I dont know why when i submit the form takes the second route instead the first one, even though I am pointing to the first one.

There must be a way to go to the same url from two different forms, that is what I want.

Comment: Why are you registering two identical routes? That's always a recipe for disaster.

Comment: They are not identicals. I just have two forms and go to the same url after posting them. One first executes login method and the other one registrarAdministrador on the AdministradorController

Comment: You have two routes for `domain.com/gestionAdministrador`. You shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have two routes with the exact same URI and same method:

```
Route::post('gestionAdministrador', array('as' => 'Loguearse', 'uses' => 'AdministradorController@Login'));

Route::post('gestionAdministrador', array('as' => 'RegistrarAdministrador', 'uses' => 'AdministradorController@RegistrarAdministrador'));
```

How can Laravel know the difference between them when something hit `/gestionAdministrador`?

It will always assume the first one.

The name you set `'as' => 'RegistrarAdministrador'` will be used to create URLs based on that route name, only, when something (browser, curl...) hit the URL the only ways to differentiate them is by

1) URL

2) URL parameters (which is basically number 1 plus parameters)

3) Method (GET, POST)

So you could change them to something like:

```
Route::post('gestionAdministrador/loguearse', array('as' => 'Loguearse', 'uses' => 'AdministradorController@Login'));

Route::post('gestionAdministrador/registrar', array('as' => 'RegistrarAdministrador', 'uses' => 'AdministradorController@RegistrarAdministrador'));
```

**EDIT 2**

What you really need to understand is that the name you give to a route ('as' => 'name') will not be part of your url, so this is not something that Laravel can use to differentiate your two URls, this is for internal use only, to identify your routes during the creation of URLs. So, those instructions:

```
$loguearse = URL::route('Loguearse');
$registrar = URL::route('RegistrarAdministrador');
```

Would generate exactly the same URL:

```
http://yourserver.dev/gestionAdministrador
```

**EDIT 1 - TO ANSWER A COMMENT**

Redirecting in Laravel is easy, in your controller, after processing your form, in any of your methods you can just:

```
return Redirect::to('/');
```

or

```
return Redirect::route('home');
```

Having a route like this one:

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index'));
```

So, your controller would look like this:

```
class AdministradorController extends Controller {

    public function RegistrarAdministrador() 
    {
        ...

        return Redirect::route('home');
    }

    public function Login() 
    {
        ...

        return Redirect::route('home');
    }
}
```

Comment: So why can i name routes in laravel. What im trying to do is from two different forms in different pages after submiting them, redirect to the same url, is that possible?

Comment: Yeah I thought of that. But sorry if I insist but isnt there any possible way to redirect to the exactly same url after submiting two different forms?

Comment: Like if I want many forms on my web after submitting go to /home, there isnt any possible way?

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro I just wanted to add to your response that he mistakenly think that aliasing (ie AS =>'') is to name the some url different when in fact its just to be able to reverse route yourself when calling from the front end.

Answer (score 3):

### Actually you have only one route in your route collection, because:

You have following routes declared:

```
Route::post('gestionAdministrador', array('as' => 'Loguearse', 'uses' => 'AdministradorController@Login'));

Route::post('gestionAdministrador', array('as' => 'RegistrarAdministrador', 'uses' => 'AdministradorController@RegistrarAdministrador'));
```

Both of these used `post` method and this is `post` method:

```
public function post($uri, $action)
{
    return $this->addRoute('POST', $uri, $action);
}
```

It calls `addRoute` and here it is:

```
protected function addRoute($methods, $uri, $action)
{
    return $this->routes->add($this->createRoute($methods, $uri, $action));
}
```

Here `$this->routes->add` means `Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection::add()` and the `add()` method calls `addToCollections()` and it is as follows:

```
protected function addToCollections($route)
{
    foreach ($route->methods() as $method)
    {
        $this->routes[$method][$route->domain().$route->getUri()] = $route;
    }

    $this->allRoutes[$method.$route->domain().$route->getUri()] = $route;
}
```

The `$routes` is an array (`protected $routes = array();`) and it's obvious that routes are grouped by `methods` (GET/POST etc) and in each method only one unique `URL` could be available because it's something like this:

```
$routes['post']['someUrl'] = 'a route';
$routes['post']['someUrl'] = 'a route';
```

So, in your case, the last one is replacing the first one and in this case you may use different methods to declare two routes using same `URL` so it would be in different array, something like this:

```
$routes['post']['someUrl'] = 'a route';
$routes['put']['someUrl'] = 'a route'; // Route::put(...)
```

> There must be a way to go to the same url from two different forms

Yes, there is a way and it's simply that you have to use the same route as the action of your form and therefore, you don't need to declare it twice.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is a bad idea, you shouldn't be logging in and registering from the same route. With that said what you are saying isn't really possible. Routing in Laravel is first come first served. Basically it checks the route until the URI matches one and then calls that method on the controller or executes the callback. Your routes have to be the other way in your routes file. This will be fixed by changing the url.

Comment: What you mean the other way? It is taking the second route and i want to take the first one. Laravel doesnt check the names. In the form i explicity put the Loguearse form. What im trying to do is from two different forms in different pages after submiting them redirect to the same url.