# Laravel - Overriding a resource route into a different route filter group

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Laravel's routing doesn't seem to be working as expected? From what I understand, if I intend to override a route, all I need to do is to put the expected route before the other one.

What I have is something like this:

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'defaultLoads'), function(){
    Route::post('newsletter', 'NewsletterController@store');

    Route::group(array('before'=>'login'), function(){
        Route::resource('newsletter','NewsletterController');
    }
});
```

Which I assumed that if i post to this route `http://domain.com/newsletter` it should only run the defaultLoads route filter.

However, when I run `php artisan routes`, I get this:

> |        | POST newsletter                                 |
>   newsletter.store      | NewsletterController@store        |
>   defaultLoads, login |               |

Although it reads the route correctly (php artisan loads that correct route in the correct place) but the resource route's filter affected the route even when it's not in that filter group.

So my question:

1. Is this how Laravel works?
2. If so, is it possible for me to override that POST->newsletter route without actually doing the following?

   ```
   Route::group(array('before'=>'defaultLoads'), function(){
   Route::post('newsletter', 'NewsletterController@store');

   Route::group(array('before'=>'login'), function(){
       Route::get('newsletter','NewsletterController@get');
       Route::get('newsletter/{id}', 'NewsletterController@show');
       //etc all the rest of the routes except post
   }});
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually overriding in that way works in cases where you need to override the actual route that is being matched. For example when you need to override a route with a parameter, with something hardcoded:

```
Route::get('newsletter/custom', ...);
Route::get('newsletter/{param}', ...); // this is overriden by the first route
```

In your case however, your route definitions are identical (both must match `newsletter` for a `post` request). That means that the last one will override the first one (and any filters applied to it in the current context). So you should be overrding it after the `resource` route definition:

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'defaultLoads'), function()
{
    Route::group(array('before'=>'login'), function()
    {
        Route::resource('newsletter','NewsletterController');
    }

    Route::post('newsletter', 'NewsletterController@store');
});
```

Your `artisan routes` for it should look like this now:

```
POST newsletter | NewsletterController@store | | defaultLoads
```

Comment: i'll try this. However, according to the docs, if 2 identical routes are found, Laravel will take the first route found. Why would Laravel take the last route found in this case?

Comment: Great, glad I could help. Could you please point out where you found the info about the identical routes precendence in the docs. There are sometimes problems with the docs and I'd like to report an issue for that if that's the case here.

Comment: Sorry I got confused. It was this post that stated it -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467677/laravel-overrides-named-route-and-takes-wrong-one