# Override resource controller method route not found

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, laravel-routing

I want to declare a get route for show that takes two parameters. I have a resource controller like this:

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController', ['except' => ['edit', 'delete']]);
```

I do not want to change that line if possible so I added above:

```
Route::get('posts/{id}/{userId}', 'PostsController@show');
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController', ['except' => ['edit', 'delete']]);
```

Yet I still get:

> Error : "X/posts/1/1" route not found.

The other tests pass.
I also tried to put the route:get below as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26927472/laravel-overriding-a-resource-route-into-a-different-route-filter-group) or add show in exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my code is correct and the problem was somewhere in the URi the correct is this one:

```
$this->get('/X/posts/' . $post['id'] . '/'. $post['userId'], $this->headers($this->user))
```

Comment: I thought or removing this question since it was a uRi minor typo but I think perhaps it can still be usefull to other users.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
Route::get('/posts', 'PostsController@show');
```

Use the url as

```
X/posts?id=1&userId=11
```

Answer (score 0):

Change order and try:

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController', ['except' => ['edit', 'delete']]);
Route::get('posts/{id}/{userId}', 'PostsController@show');
```

Comment: The order I have works for me it was probably something in the URi when I wrote it again it was fine.